# div height for an inner div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm appending a `div` inside another `div` like this:

```
$('#maindivid').append('<div id="newid" style="background: url(xyz/image/test.png); position:absolute; min-height:100%; width:100%; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px; overflow:auto;"></div>');
```

But my new `div` doesn't get the entire height of the container `div`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: $('#maindivid').append('<div id="childid"  style="background: url(test.png); position:absolute; min-height:100%; width:100%; height:inherit; top:0px; left:0px; overflow:auto;"></div>');

Comment: can you show us the parent html code with css? and the child that you want to append?

Comment: Parent div: <div id="maindivid “ scrollleft="0" scrolltop="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 561.4px;" class="class-new " >

Comment: Child div: $('#maindivid').append('<div id="childid" style="background: url(test.png); position:absolute; min-height:100%; width:100%; height:inherit; top:0px; left:0px; overflow:auto;"></div>');

Comment: With position relative seem to work: [SEE_HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JanT8/)

Answer (score 0):

set the attribute of the new div to `height:inherit`;

Comment: r u properly opening & closing div tags??

Comment: It still doesnt work. Ok let me explain you my scenario. I have a jstree inside the main div. And on a button click say I am trying to append the child div to the main div whose height increases as the tree nodes are expanded.

Comment: I just checked the parent div height is 560px.

Comment: what browser r u testing on??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the parent div, then setting the height of the child to 100%.

Comment: Is it possible w/o setting the parent's height as its already created and I am taking its id dynamically.

Comment: The height css property is going to trickle down the dom.  If you have a percentage based height and the parent has no height specified, then the child cannot determine what 100% is.  An alternative that may work for you would be to set the position to absolute and the top and bottom properties to 0.  Not ideal but not being able to specify the parent's heights isn't either.

Comment: If the parent div has no height then what would the child div be conforming to? I think you might need to post some sample code.

Comment: I just checked the parent div height is 560px.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Div:

```
<div id="maindivid" scrollleft="0" scrolltop="0" style="border:1px solid black; width: auto; height: 561.4px;" class="class-new " >
       Parent Border
</div>​
```

script to append the child:

```
 $('#maindivid').append('<div id="childid" style="border: 1px solid red; position:absolute; width:100%; height:inherit; ">Child</div>'); ​
```

this works on jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/qY47q/

Note: I did remove the height:100% on the child because you've already specify that the height will be inherit to the parent. Also, I added border so that I could see the actual height of the div

Comment: Somehow I cannot achieve 100% height, but anyways thanks a ton to all. Maybe there is some other issue.